# Assess statistical significance with before & after binomial data from few participants

Tags: statistical-significance, repeated-measures, binomial-distribution, small-sample

For the quantitative analysis of a pedagogical approach, I applied a series of (equivalent) tests prior and after lessons. I want to evaluate the reading (proper identification of sounds from written symbols) capacity of illiterate adults. Each evaluation consists of a list of ~25 words (each reading can be assigned either as right or wrong), and the same lists were applied to 9 subjects, with no control group, before and after each lesson. My advisor and I are happy with this methodology, since a qualitative analysis will be performed too.

I know it's hard to define what is a real result and what is randomness in these situations, so I would really like to know what my options are to ensure the improvements we noticed were more than luck (again, the question here isn't about the methodology, but about the data analysis). My first thought is to take the number right I would get from random answering (I believe that a it'll be something like a Gaussian distribution) and see if my results are in the right tail of the curve. Is this approach reasonable? What are my options?

Comment: How many lessons are to be taught and how many pedagogical approaches are you using?  Are there 25x9 questions or 25 questions?  How were the questions chosen?

Comment: What type or types of questions are there?  Essay, multiple choice, calculations?

Comment: @DaveHarris, OP indicates they are True/False (i.e.g right or wrong).